# PHP Mail not formated for some reason

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and send an email using following code

```
<?php
$to      = 'to@xyz.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = '<table dir="rtl"><tr><td>'. "\r\n";
$message .= '<b>This  is Bold</b></br> <i> This is Italics</i></br>شطب 14 مرشحا لمجلس الأمة الكويتي'. "\r\n";
$message .= '</td></tr></table>';
//Headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n" .
$headers .= 'From: from@xyz.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: replyto@xyz.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



ini_set ( "SMTP", "smtp.xyz.com" );

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

I can receive the email and it display the arabic also but it also show the from email address in the body of the email.

And other issue is that arabic is RTL even after mentioning in table dir-"RTL" it still show the message as LTR.

Example of Email Received

```
from@xyz.com
This is Bold
This is Italics
شطب 14 مرشحا لمجلس الأمة الكويتي
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the alternative of CSS2 style:

```
style="direction:RTL; unicode-bidi:embed;"
```

Extra reading: http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html

Comment: It doesnt work, i can live with it but more important is the fisrt issue.